# Низкая скорость работы программы (python - excel)

Tags: python, excel

Товарищи. В питоне новичок, так что не бейте)

Задача следующая: есть два файла эксель с данными, каждый по несколько десятков тысяч строк. Назовём их файлы А и Б

В [А] колонке табличек каждого файла записаны наименования категорий (одна строчка - одна категория). При этом, в файле Б отсутствует несколько тысяч категорий в сравнении с файлом А.

Необходимо: достать данные из последней колонки файла Б и перезаписать в последнюю колонку файла А.

Однако, из-за того, что не все категории соответствуют, я не могу просто сделать сортировку и скопировать столбец. Приходится сначала проверять, соответствует ли категория, а потом уже перезаписывать.

Это дело у меня реализовано через openpyxl обычным перебором, циклом «for внутри for» плюс ещё if затесался, и работает это все невероятно долго.

Может чего подскажете.
Ещё раз задача, только кратко:

1. сверить значение в столбцах [А] в двух разных файлах
2. если совпало на какой-то строчке, перезаписать значение из последнего столбца файла Б в последний столбец файла А

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: а код покажите?

Comment: Прочитайте все содержимое файла B и сложите [словарь](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/slovari-dict-funkcii-i-metody-slovarej.html).  Обращения для к словарю - быстрее чем перебор.